# How to use patchValues() with the <mat-form-field > on the (keyup.enter) event binding

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to populate the city based on zip code field. I am able to do the aforementioned using normal  html tag with the (keyup) event binding, but with  css I have to use (keyup.enter) which is able to invoke the function which is bind with event call but it is not letting the patchValue() function work properly. Here's a snippet of my code :-

**editor.component.ts**

```
profileForm = this.fb.group({
    name: ['', Validators.required],
    address: this.fb.group({
             zip: ['', Validators.required],
             city: ['', Validators.required]})
             });


func(event: any){
  this.profileForm.patchValue({
      address:{
      city: this.getCity(event.value)
      }
    })  
}

getCity = (theCurrentZip: any) => {
  return Object.keys(this. zipCode).filter(z => {
    return this.zipCode[z].includes(theCurrentZip)
  })[0]
}

zipCode: any = {
  "A": ["1", "2" ],
  "B":[ "3", "4",]
};
```

**editor.component.html**

```
<div>
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #myForm="ngForm" class="profileForm">
<mat-form-field required>
  <input matInput id="name" placeholder="Contact Name" name="name" [(ngModel)]="name">
</mat-form-field >
<div formGroupName="address">
<mat-form-field >
    <input matInput id="zip" (keyup)="func($event.target)" placeholder="Zip" name="zip" [(ngModel)]="zip" >
  </mat-form-field >
  <mat-form-field required>
    <input matInput id="city" placeholder="City" name="city" [(ngModel)]="city" >
  </mat-form-field >
</div>
<p>
    <button type="submit" mat-raised-button color = "primary">Submit</button>
</p>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: As far as I can see you're mixing the reactive and template-driven form from Angular here. I think, you issue results from that. So try to set `this.city` in `func` and that should work here.

Comment: That's correct, as I had just replaced reactive with mat-form-field, meanwhile I have already tried using this.city but it gives syntax error
`code`
this.city: this.getCity(event.target.value)
`code`

Comment: In a reactive form you don't need to patch values, you can simply say `func() { this.city = this.getCity(...) }`

Comment: Thanks that worked !
Sorry I was making a basic error about reactive form. Thanks for clearing that out

Comment: @Batajus could you also post this as an answer so I can accept it..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see you're currently mixing the [reactive](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) and [template-driven](https://angular.io/guide/forms) approach of Angular forms.

The reactive approach is used in your `editor.component.ts` and the template-driven one in your `editor.component.html`.

Since your HTML is template-driven it is not necessary to call `patchValue` because the form and the form controls are not bound to the HTML. So, to update your HTML you need to adjust your implementation of `func` like following

```
func(event) {
  this.city = this.getCity(event.target.value);
}
```

My suggestion for you would be that you **choose one** of those approaches and **don't mix** them (if it isn't absolutely necessary). Also, you should use more meaningful function names than `func` ;)

Comment: thanks again Batajus!